# How to change reducer to create slice in redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

```
 import { combineReducers } from "redux";
 const initialState = {
     sidebarShow: true,
  }
   const changeState = (state = initialState, { type, ...rest }) => {
     switch (type) {
       case 'set':
        return { ...state, ...rest }
      default:
         return state
   }
  }
   export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
     nav: changeState
   })
```

1.how to change this code to createslice format in redux toolkit

Answer (score 2):

you need to follow [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start)

```
  import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
    
 const initialState = {
     sidebarShow: true,
  }
    
    export const counterSlice = createSlice({
      name: 'changeState',
      initialState,
      reducers: {
        set: (state, action) => {
        state = {...state , action.payload}
},

      },
    })
    export const { set } = counterSlice.actions
    
    export default counterSlice.reducer
```